# AWS Dynamodb put a list of Objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I've a list of Objects:
[[id,name,latitude,longitude],[id,name,latitude,longitude] ] etc..

I would like to push the list to a dynamodb table named Stations.
This is what i did:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
function Station(id, name, latitude, longitude){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
var stations = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < event.length;i++){
    stations[i] = new Station(event[i][0],event[i][1],event[i]
[2],event[i][3]);
    } 
var params = {
TableName: "Stations",
Item: stations
};

DynamoDB.put(params, function (err) {
 if (err) {
     console.log("ERROR :"+ err)
 }
    console.log("SUCCESS DynamoDB PUT")
  });
```

}

Error i get:

**:ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item**

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are putting an item to a DynamoDB table, you need to include the Hash Key and Sort Key(If available) in the parameters to create or update.

To put a list of items, you cannot use `DynamoDB.put` method. Instead you need to use `DynamoDB.batchWrite`.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
function Station(id, name, latitude, longitude){
    this.PutRequest = {
       Item: {
          id: id,
          name: name,
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude
       }
    };
}
var stations = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < event.length;i++){
    stations[i] = new Station(event[i][0],event[i][1],event[i]
[2],event[i][3]);
    } 
var params = {
  RequestItems: {
    'Stations': stations
  }
};
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
documentClient.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

Reference: [AWS DynamoDB Document Client JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property)

Note: Assuming id, name, latitude or longitude attribute contains the hash key and sort key(If available).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added the workaround for the 25 element limit still having some issues on the callback not getting triggered.